# How to get corresponding numpy array values after performing calculation on another related array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function that returns two NumPy arrays (width and height) like so:

```
width, height = calc_heigh_width(data)

width
>>> array([390, 20, 65, 1000])

height
>>> array([2, 7, 3, 1])
```

Imagine the widths as being points on an x-axis, so they go from 0 to 1000 in this example, similarly for the height.

I am only interested in places where the current width is bigger than the previous width by 600 and less than the previous width by 800. So I wrote this to solve that:

```
import numpy as np

sorted_width_array = np.sort(width)

width_calc_list = []
for i in range(len(sorted_width_array) - 1):
    if ((sorted_width_array[i+1] - sorted_width_array[i]) > 600) and ((sorted_width_array[i+1] - sorted_width_array[i]) < 800):
        width_calc_list.append(sorted_width_array[i])
        width_calc_list.append(sorted_width_array[i+1])
```

This returns

```
width_calc_list
>>> [390, 1000]
```

However, I would also like to get the height values that correspond to these width values but I just haven't been able to solve it. Any help is much appreciated.

So basically, I'd like to get something like this

```
height_calc_list
>>> [2, 1]
```

PS: I know my current code to find the width works but if there's any way to improve it I'm all ears. I was playing around with NumPy's diff function and I'm optimistic that will work but haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Hi, I accidentally copied the wrong thing. My bad. It's weird that it was working on my jupyter notebook. I edited it now. Oh and I sort because like is said, the values are like values on an x-axis, so I'm looking for places where the width is in that range because there's an object I'm trying to find there. My thought process might be wrong but this is my current approach.

Comment: if you sort it you loose the information about the order. if thats fine then fine.

Comment: @RitwickJha oh, I thought there was probably still a way to save the indices and just use that to subset the height array.

Comment: if you sort it, it becomes [20, 65, 390, 1000] so 390 and 1000 are selected. if [390, 20, 65, 1000] then nothing will be selected. you understand?

Comment: @RitwickJha Yeah it totally makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

you can just zip the values and use the same algorithm you have written. i did not check the correctness of your solution, just changed it so that it returns the format you want. check it out

```
width = [390, 20, 65, 1000]
height = [2, 7, 3, 1]

cord = sorted(list(zip(width, height)), key=lambda tup: tup[0])
print(cord)

width_calc_list = []
for i in range(len(cord) - 1):
    if ((cord[i+1][0] - cord[i][0]) > 600) and ((cord[i+1][0] - cord[i][0]) < 800):
        width_calc_list.append(cord[i])
        width_calc_list.append(cord[i+1])
        
print(width_calc_list)
#[(390, 2), (1000, 1)]
```